# Approximation of connected set by triangluation / covering by simplices

Tags: convex-polytopes, triangulations, covering

Good afternoon. I have two distinct questions:

- If I have connected compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how much $(n+1)$-simplices are needed to fill its interior such that diameter of maximal uncovered part is less than $\varepsilon$;
- If I have connected compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how much $(n+1)$-simplices are needed to cover this set such that maximal distance from point in covering to the set is less than $\varepsilon$.

I'm interested in characterising sets for which one of the counts described is $O(poly(n, \varepsilon^{-1}))$. As I understand, even for polyhedra with $p$ vertices current upper bound is $p^{O(d)}$ (I'm not sure, I look in "On the Size of Higher-Dimensional Triangulations", Peter Brass). Its interesting for me which sets require $O(poly(n, \varepsilon^{-1}))$ in one case but not $O(poly(n, \varepsilon^{-1}))$ in another. Especially, I'm interested in convex sets and connection of those counts to asphericity of the set.

Where could I read more about these questions?